# drive file stream has encountered a problem and has stopped

Tags: google-apps, mojave

I had installed [Google Drive File Streaming](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7491144?utm_medium=et&utm_source=aboutdrive&utm_content=getstarted&utm_campaign=en_us) and it was working fine until I upgraded to Mojave. Thereafter, I keep getting the error:
"drive file stream has encountered a problem and has stopped"
Dmesg reports:

```
Kext com.google.dfsfuse.filesystems.dfsfuse start failed (result 0x5).
Kext com.google.dfsfuse.filesystems.dfsfuse failed to load (0xdc008017).
Failed to load kext com.google.dfsfuse.filesystems.dfsfuse (error 0xdc008017).
syscall_extension_consume failed: 22syscall_extension_consume failed: 2
```

I have Virtualbox and Keybase installed, as well as OSXFuse. Not sure if they're competing / conflicting.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this still an issue for you? Have you tried System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> General -> "Allow..." to ensure third party extensions are allowed and (re) add the "Google Drive File Stream" to the list; then System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Privacy Accessibility to add/enable it in "Allow apps below to control your computer." If this helps I'll add it as an answer, but I'm not sure it's your problem.

Comment: It looks like it depends on the order that applications start up and how many you have that require Fuse. Right now, seems to have sorted itself out.

Answer (score 1):

had the same problem for weeks now and was just able to solve it by uninstalling VirtualBox

Comment: I need both, so not a solution for me

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on a brand new Mac google support resolved the issue these where the steps

1. From the Apple menu select Restart.
2. As your Mac restarts, press and hold down the Command(⌘) + R keys immediately upon hearing the startup chime. Hold the keys until the Apple logo appears to get the computer in Recovery mode.
3. The computer is now in Recovery mode. From the Apple menu select Utilities -> Terminal
4. Run the command: csrutil disable
5. From the Apple menu, select Restart.
6. After the macOS is loaded, open terminal and type: sudo kextcache -invalidate /
7. Run Drive File Stream again.

Comment: That will disable System Integrity Protection on the Mac, which doesn't sound like a good idea.